# Is there a way to fill a collection cell with two labels (fixed-scale-width) in xib?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I'm a newer to iOS, and start to use auto layout in xib. 

These days I ran into an issue: **Is there a way to fill a collection cell with two labels (fixed-scale-width, say, the scale is 3:1) in xib? If xib cannot do this, then how to do to achieve this?**

And, I haven't turn to Swift yet, so the solution must not only for Swift.

Hope your answer, many thanks!




PS: Aspect Ratio can be the solution? But is it just a ratio for one label's width and height? as follows:
[image]

But, what I wanted is just let  the ratio of widths of item1 and item2 be 3:1, no matter with the height! 

**`Another problem is: if the cell height changed, but the width not, the ratio can keep to be 3:1?`**

Comment: Not clear enough? I mean, the widths of the two labels have the fixed scale. Thus, if the cell is 280px width, then label one will be 210px width, label two will be 70px width; while cell changed to 720px width, then label one will be 540px width, label two will be 180px.

Comment: If only cell height changed, then both labels' height changed, but the width should not be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1. Create a xib
2. Add a collection view cell
3. Add two labels to it
4. Control-drag from the label to itself. Set the aspect ratio to 3:1
5. Do the same for the other label
6. Add the other necessary constraints to each label.

I had no problems doing this? Did you come across a specific issue?

Comment: Aspect ratio? The height involved or not? If so, the weight of the width of both labels will be changed, what I never want.

Comment: @kenmux I can't understand your request, but it sounds very basic. You should just learn how to use autolayout: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I'm sorry, just cannot catch you. I edit the question for the third time. Am I missed something? Thanks for listen to me patiently, I am just a newer.

Comment: Before asking this question, I visited that page several times. But I get no answer. Did I misunderstand something?